# Why accessing static variable cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS after app switch?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, static-variables

I have a static variable defined like this:

```
class Engine {
   static weak var attachedViewController:UIViewController? = nil
}

// In ViewDidLoad of the view controller, the static variable is assigned 
Engine.attachedViewController = self

// Later, an app switch is triggered (sharing content to another app), 
// after switching back, app crashes on this line:
Engine.attachedViewController.do_something()
```

<strike>Now I solved the problem by reassigning in `ViewDidAppear` of the ViewController:</strike>

```
// in ViewDidAppear
Engine.attachedViewController = self
```

But I don't understand what is happening here, why is the static variable reassigned to `nil`. Do I need to use a singleton instead?

Actually, scratch what I said. The crash is not due to `.attachedViewController` set to nil. Accessing `Engine.attachedViewController` cause the crash (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`).

This static variable is accessed within a closure like this:

I defined a custom Button, add assign its action from code:

```
class ActionButton: FlatButton {
var action: (() -> ())?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    print("HERE")
    sharedInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    print("HERE2")
    sharedInit()
}

private func sharedInit() {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
    self.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 30)
    addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchUpInside), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc private func touchUpInside() {
    action?()
}
}
```

The actions are assigned when constructing UI, the action closures are obtained from:

```
   func get_action_for_command_key(key:String) -> ()->Void {
    switch key {
        case "ABC": return {
            Engine.markResponded()
            // The following line is where app crashes
            let url = Engine.UI?.itemurl
        }
 }
```

My guess now: it's somehow related to closure capturing the static value. But I still don't understand why accessing the variable is bad access after app switch.

Comment: Debug it with `didSet` in variable and look what's happening. Also your variable should be weak, otherwise your UIViewController will never be deinitialized.

Comment: Yes you should use a static singleton there